# Angular-UI-Calendar Late Binding?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, calendar, fullcalendar, angular-ui

I am using Angular-UI's calendar which I really like.  However, I am having an issue with late binding.

The directive is like this:

```
<div ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar" ng-model="eventSources" calendar="myCalendar" class="cal-self panel panel-custom">
```

The `eventSources` comes from a substantial server-side API request.  The request always completes after the calendar has already rendered to the page.

Any ideas on having this be able to be late bound?

Answer (score 2):

I've had success with this by doing the following: I'll give the line numbers for the current source file on ui-calendar's repo. After the call to `getFullCalendarConfig` do: ~line-203  -- you'll need to inject `$timeout`

```
var viewChanged = false,
    oldViewDisplay = fullCalendarConfig.viewDisplay || fullCalendarConfig.viewRender;
delete fullCalendarConfig.viewDisplay;
fullCalendarConfig.viewRender = function(view){
    if(oldViewDisplay)oldViewDisplay(view);
    viewChanged = true;
    $timeout(function(){viewChanged = false});
};
```

and then inside the function passed to `eventWatcher.subscribe(scope...` do:  ~line 255

```
if (!viewChanged)
    scope.calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');           
if (sourcesChanged === true) {
    // Rerender the whole thing if a new event source was added/removed
    scope.calendar.fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
    sourcesChanged = false;
    // prevent incremental updates in this case
    return false;
}
```

**Update**

So I've made a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Sx5ECU).
It basically has a simplified/mangled ui-calendar directive (of v0.1.2|3 era). However, It could be said (IMHO) that the directive is 'over angularized' as fullcalendar functions very well with it's own devices (which are many and proven).

Comment: I've added a plunker, I hope this solution will help!